# NGINX connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/forums.socket failed

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm

I recently set up my server again with nginx, PHP-FPM. i did what I always do but now the nginx or php-fpm doesn't process php files. ( I test with the simplest form of php phpinfo(); ).

In the error log of my VHOST i get :

```
2013/12/01 03:59:12 [crit] 1201#0: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/forums.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 173.245.53.199, server: forums.DOMAIN.DOM, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/forums.socket:", host: "forums.DOMAIN.DOM", referrer: "http://forums.DOMAIN.DOM/"
```

the funny thing is that the directory mentioned in the error is there but php-fpm or nginx doesn't spawn the socket there.

resources:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6502117/

Comment: in **/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/forums.conf** change the `user = (THE USERNAME OF THE USER THAT OWNS THE SITE FILES)` to `user = nginx`

Comment: Then restart the nginx and php5-fpm services.

Comment: if you found that the **/var/run/php5-fpm/** is not writable change the owner-ship of that folder
`sudo chown -R nginx:www-data /var/run/php5-fpm/` change the `nginx:www-data` to what user:group you set in your **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**